# How do I minify specific files using laravel-mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I am trying to find a way to minimize specific files using laravel-mix. From the [documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.1/installation) it specifies you are able to minify files using `npm run prod`. My goal is to minify file `a.js` but not `b.js`. Is this possible through `webpack.mix.json` config file or through the `npm` command alias in `package.json`?

Versions:

laravel-mix@1.7.2

npm@6.4.1

laravel@5.5.48

Answer (score 0):

this is example to minify specific files

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

// 1. A single src and output path.
mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist/app.js');

// 2. For additional src files that should be
// bundled together:
mix.js([
    'src/app.js',
    'src/another.js'
], 'dist/app.js');

// 3. For multiple entry/output points:
mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist/')
   .js('src/forum.js', 'dist/');
```